# Datareader value in JavaScript array

Tags: asp.net, javascript

I want to fetch Image name, and 3 more field's value from a database and pass it to the JavaScript array which would be generate from the database (Image name and 3 field)

http://www.dynamicdrive.com/dynamicindex14/leftrightslide.htm

```
var leftrightslide=new Array()
var finalslide=''
leftrightslide[cnt]='<a href="http://MY DEFAULT.ASPX?Value from database"><img src="IMAGEFROMDATABASE.gif" border=1></a>'
cnt++
```

Comment: Same as this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1852114/how-to-get-a-server-side-variable-into-javascript

Answer (score 0):

for interaction between javascript and scripting languages use AJAX

XMLHTTPRequest object

Answer (score 0):

```js
function fndisn(e)
{
    var key1 = document.all ? e.keyCode : e.which;
    return (key1 > 64 && key1 < 91) || (key1 > 96 && key1 < 123);
}
```

Comment: Javascript for check character value in text box.